# Obtain a list of non-admin file shares from multiple Windows servers

Tags: windows, powershell, fileshare

GOAL: Obtain a CSV file with the following information:

- Computer Name
- Share Name
- Share Path
- Share Description

for all non-admin (type 0) SMB shares on all servers from a list (txt file).

INITIAL CODE:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $path
)

$computers = Get-Content $path
$shareInfo = @()

ForEach ($computer in $computers) {
    $shares = gwmi -Computer $computer -Class Win32_Share -filter "Type = 0" | Select Name,Path,Description

    $shares | % {
        $ShareName = $_.Name
        $Props = [ordered]@{
            Computer = $computer
            ShareName = $_.Name
            Path = $shares.Path
            Description = $shares.Description
        }
    }

    $ShareInfo += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Props
}

$shareInfo | Export-CSV -Path .\shares.csv -NoType
```

CODE OUTPUT:

```
"Computer","ShareName","Path","Description"
"SERVER1","SHARE1","System.Object[]","System.Object[]"
"SERVER2","SHARE12","System.Object[]","System.Object[]"
"SERVER3","SHARE3","System.Object[]","System.Object[]"
```

PROBLEM:

While the code provides output for each server, it seems to not include all shares from the servers. Furthermore, the Path and Description fields are not populated with good information.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

The code:

```
$shares = gwmi -Computer $computer -Class Win32_Share -filter "Type = 0" | Select Name,Path,Description
```

Produces good information as below:

```
Name           Path                                Description
----           ----                                -----------
print$         C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\drivers   Printer Drivers
Share          D:\Share
SHARE2         D:\SHARE2
Software       C:\Software                         The Software
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$shares | % {
    $ShareName = $_.Name
    $Props = [ordered]@{
        Computer = $computer
        ShareName = $_.Name
        Path = $shares.Path
        Description = $shares.Description
    }
}
```

You're using `$shares` instead of `$_` for the `Path` and `Description` properties, so each of these properties is assigned a list of the values of the respective property of each element of the `$shares` collection.

Also, why are you building custom objects in the first place when you just need to filter the WMI query results? The computer name can be obtained from the `__SERVER` (or `PSMachineName`) property. Plus, type 0 means a shared disk drive, not an administrative share. You need to filter the latter by other criteria (usually description and/or share name).

```
$filter = "Type = 0 And Description != 'Default Share' And " +
          "Name != 'ADMIN$' And Name != 'IPC$'"

$computers |
  ForEach-Object { Get-WmiObject -Computer $_ -Class Win32_Share -Filter $filter } |
  Select-Object @{n='Computer';e={$_.__SERVER}}, Name, Path, Description |
  Export-Csv -Path .\shares.csv -NoType
```

Comment: The missing pipeline variables was due to coding fatigue. I'm sure I would have caught those... eventually. :) Also, I built custom objects because I'm not very good with WMI and only knew how to add CSV columns via objects. I'm learning more and more each day. Appreciate the answer!